# Download file from url on C++

Tags: c++, file, url

I have C ++ code that should download a file from a URL and save it in some directory. I implemented this. But I do not know how to implement the server side. URL to download file
C++ code

```
string dwnld_URL = "127.0.0.1/screenchote.png";
string savepath = "D:\\screenchote.png";
URLDownloadToFile(NULL, dwnld_URL.c_str(), savepath.c_str(), 0, NULL);
```

dwnload_URl = url where we must download file

savepath = save file in path

how to make the server side?

Comment: How does `URLDownloadToFile()` operate? Have you checked the MSDN for documentation? That should give you a hint how it operates and how to implement the server-side of this. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: No, no info in msdn, only link

Comment: You want to make a server provide files to be downloaded from specified URL? One have to implement a web server. This is a question too big to explain in one post. Or google for "how to host a web server".

Comment: May be i need it. I don't know how to implement. Need create link-downloader

Comment: Now I got your question. A server downloading files by provided links. Not the server of the URL. Then it's a easier question, but SO answers a specifice question about code. So i'd suggest edit your post for "what kind of server and behavior you want" and your effort of code.

Comment: Example php on anyserver, i use openserver. I just need code on php, which create link download file. P.s i never work with back-end and php.

Comment: You want to write server. Application that will make link "127.0.0.1/screenshots.png" available for download from your computer ?
By C++ code or web browser.
Do I understand your question correctly ?
You can use ready servers like Xampp

Answer (score 0):

It's very helpful but its need some development and improvement:

```
#include<tchar.h>
#include<urlmon.h>

#pragma comment (lib,"urlmon.lib")

int main ()
{
  HRESULT hr=Urldownloadtofile( NULL, _T("your web page"), _T("c:/web_page.html") 0, NULL );

  return 0;
}
```

Or

```
HRESULT hr = Urldownloadtofile( NULL, L"your web page", L"c:/web_page.html", 0, NULL );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use the URLDownloadToFile() function to download any content from the internet like /files etc...

If you want to pass the URL and file path as variables use this method

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // URL & FILE PATH IN STRING
    string FilePath = "D:\test\image.png";
    string URL = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg"; 


    wstring tempUrl = wstring(URL.begin(), URL.end());
    wstring tempPath = wstring(FilePath.begin(), FilePath.end());

    // Applying c_str() method on temp
    LPCWSTR wideStringUrl = tempUrl.c_str();
    LPCWSTR wideStringPath = tempPath.c_str();

    // URL must include the HTTPS/HTTP.
    if (S_OK == URLDownloadToFile(NULL, wideStringUrl, wideStringPath, 0, NULL)) {
         cout << "Downlod: Succses" << endl;
    } else {
         cout << "Download: Fails" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> // URL must include the HTTPS/HTTP.

If you want to pass the URL and the save path directly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    if (S_OK == URLDownloadToFile(NULL, L"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg", L"D:\test\image.png", 0, NULL)) {
        cout << "Downlod: Succses" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Download: Fails" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> **File PATH** = The path of the file where you want the content to be saved.
>
> **URL**= It is the address of the site you want to download, for example, the url of an image or a text file

[> -> URLDownloadToFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85))